# Delete button without { Component } in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is surely really easy but I didn't find the solution.. I want to use the delete button but I'm getting an error. Thanks in advance guys.

This is the code where props call the properties of a Toy class parent, I want to delete by Id using MongoDB:

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import UserContext from '../../context/UserContext';
import Axios from 'axios';

export default function AdminOptions(props) {

    const { userData } = useContext(UserContext);

    console.log(props.value._id)
    //I tried this log and it gives me the id of the toy
    
    deleteToy = async(id) => {
        await Axios.delete('api/toys/delete' + id);
        alert('Toy deleted');
    }
    

    return (
        
        <div>
                {userData.user ? (
                <>      
                <br/>       
                <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.deleteToy(props.value._id)}>
                    Delete toy
                </button>
                
                </>
            ) : (
                <>
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

And this is the error I get

```
Failed to compile.

  Line 15:5:  'deleteToy' is not defined  no-undef
```

Comment: `this.deleteToy = async(id) => {`.

Comment: No. `const deleteToy = ...` and `onClick={deleteToy(...`

Comment: Could you elaborate on how it's wrong?

Comment: Because `this` refers to the `window` object in functional components, it doesn't make any sense to define variables as window properties. Read up on the difference between functional and class components.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Because `this` will be either `window` (in which case you would create a global variable, which will fail horribly once you use more than one instance of the component!) or, in case of strict mode enabled, `undefined` (in which case you will get an error `Cannot write property 'deleteToy' of undefined`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are using the variable `deleteToy` without defining it (with either `const`, `let` or `var`), hence the error.
2. You are referring to `this.deleteToy`, yet your variable is just `deleteToy`.
3. In your event handler, you are not passing a function reference but actually calling the function right away. You can prepend `() =>` to fix it (passing an arrow function that then calls yours when called). (Thanks, Emre Koc, I missed that.)

The fixed code would look like this:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import UserContext from '../../context/UserContext';
import Axios from 'axios';

export default function AdminOptions(props) {

    const { userData } = useContext(UserContext);

    console.log(props.value._id)
    //I tried this log and it gives me the id of the toy
    
    const deleteToy = async(id) => {
        await Axios.delete('api/toys/delete' + id);
        alert('Toy deleted');
    }

    return (    
        <div>
                {userData.user ? (
                <>      
                <br/>       
                <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => deleteToy(props.value._id)}>
                    Delete toy
                </button>
                
                </>
            ) : null}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Add const before deleteToy . It will work

Comment: It won't because the OP then accesses `this.deleteToy` instead of `deleteToy` which will be undefined.

Comment: <button onClick={() => deleteToy(3)}>Button</button>    const deleteToy = async (id) => {
    alert(id);
  };  , for me working

Comment: Yes -  but the OP has `this.deleteToy(props.value._id)` in their code, did you see it?